# How to remove this bottom keyboard section for emoji and mic buttons in react native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, emoji, textinput, react-native-textinput

Does anyone know how to remove this bottom section of the keyboard on react-native iOS? Maybe a secret keyboardType prop on a TextInput or something?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did my solution help you or you have any other problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that just removed the little smiley face from the bottom left. But the bar was still there: https://imgur.com/a/2U4MvKS ... Thanks though